# How do I simply create a patch from my latest git commit?

Tags: git, patch

I am looking for the command for creating a patch from the last commit made.

My workflow sometimes looks like this:

```
vi some.txt
git add some.txt
git commit -m "some change"
```

Now I just want to write:

```
git create-patch-from-last-commit-to-file SOME-PATCH0001.patch
```

What should I put there instead of `create-patch-from-last-commit-to-file`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a git patch for a specific commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit)

Comment: A good source: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

Comment: Required preliminary setup info (my own Q&A): [How to configure and use `git send-email` to work with gmail to email patches to developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238913/4561887)

Answer (score 359, accepted):

In general,

```
git format-patch -n HEAD^
```

(check help for the many options), although it's really for mailing them.
For a single commit just

```
git show HEAD > some-patch0001.patch
```

will give you a useable patch.

Comment: this one i shorter, which is good. git show HEAD > SOME-PATCH0001.patch would solve my problem, thank you!

Comment: be carefull with "git show HEAD > some-patch0001.patch", if it'S called in colored terminal it dups also color escape sequences into file.

Comment: You can also use `git diff > change.patch`. You can include a revision range as well and it allows you to create patches for uncommitted changes. The big difference, however, is that _it will not include differences in binary files_. See the answer to [What is the difference between 'git format-patch' and 'git diff'?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4624292/2506021) for more detail.

Comment: @hrach not on Linux it doesn't

Comment: Isn't the first line wrong? For the last commit, it should be HEAD and not HEAD^. (git format-patch -1 HEAD^ will NOT generate a patch for the last commit).

Comment: No, because that isn't what the first line says. Either `git format-patch -1` or `git format-patch -n HEAD^` should work.

Comment: Thanks, I had not understood that it was literally the letter 'n', I thought it was a placeholder (format-patch has both '-n' and '-<n>' options).

Comment: @Useless can you please be kind enough to explain me what it is the purpose of using the `-n` sign, I read the Doc but couldn't get a clear idea, can please explain it in simple forms, as I am new to git

Comment: Try it (with and without `-n`) and see, it won't break anything. It just affects how the patch file is named.

Comment: `git show HEAD` and `git diff` generated different results @RangiKeen

Comment: @alper You'd use `git diff HEAD~..HEAD` to show the differences in only the last commit. The only difference between that and `git show HEAD` is that the latter includes the commit information at the beginning.

Answer (score 72):

Taking from @Useless answer, you can also use the general form with no parameters for the last commit and put it into a file with:

```
git format-patch HEAD^ --stdout > patchfile.patch
```

Or, being cleaner for windows users when carets have to be escaped by doubling them:

```
git format-patch HEAD~1 --stdout > patchfile.patch
```

Comment: Worked for me - thanks. If you happen to use Windows and Git, you have to escape the carrot (I know heinous): "git format-patch HEAD^^ --stdout > patchfile.patch"

Comment: To avoid the Windows problem of having to escape that caret (which makes it look like a different valid git command), you can use the alternative of `git format-patch HEAD~1`.  I think that ends up being less confusing on Windows.

Comment: you can also use -o flag instead of --stdout.

`git format-patch HEAD^ -o ./patchfile.patch`

Answer (score 34):

another way, if have the commit id of that particular commit, 
you can use,

```
git format-patch -1 {commit-id}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
git format-patch -1
```

Does the job for me.

Answer (score 12):

You need the `-p` option to git log:

```
git log -1 -p --pretty='%b'
```

Comment: Use this one if you don't care for the email from/date/subject lines at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you are pushing code in branch "branch_name" on Github. Every commit on this branch will have separate url. Click on latest commit.

1. Add **.patch** at the end of this url . So the modified url looks like:
   **https://github.com/xyz/lmn-ms/tree/branch_name.patch**.
2. Then copy and paste the entire content which will come in step1 in separate
   local file and save it with .patch extention.
3. Patch is ready to use.

Comment: This helped me quickly generate a patch from a single commit when git was picking up thousands of extra commits due to unrelated history w.r.t. current branch