# git: Patch does not have a valid e-mail address

Tags: git, patch, git-patch

I have a patch-file.

I want to apply this patch to my code in git repository.

When I used subversion this process was quite simple: right click -> tortoise svn -> apply patch. It always works as I expected.

But I cannot do this using git. Git doesn't apply my patch. It complains about

**Patch does not have a valid e-mail address.**

So, my question is:
"How apply patch file in this situation?"

Answer (score 9):

Git created patches are meant to be applied with Git tools.  Use

```
git apply <patch>
```

If the patch is not created with Git, then just use a patch program 'behind the back' of Git. Often this is the program 'patch':

```
patch <patch>
```

After applying the patch, add and commit in Git as usual.

Comment: Exactly this command doesn't work. I wrote above that git complains about missed email.

Comment: Did you create the patch with Git?

Comment: No. This is a "unified" patch format generated by tortoise diff viewer.

Comment: See updated answer; apply the patch 'behind the back' of Git.

Answer (score 6):

This works with *mbox* files downloaded from *pipermail* used by many open source projects.  This probably doesn't work in the OP's case, but the same symptom/question results when using `git am` with *pipermail* extracted messages/patches.

---

Make a backup of the file and edit it to add a line,

```
From: name@domain.com (Proper Name)
```

Often the line already exists, but **anti-spam** features may have converted the `@` sign to the text *at*.  You can patch a bunch of files with a gnu `sed` command like,

```
sed -ie 's/\(From:.*\) at /\1@/' *.patch
```

This just replaces ' at ' with the `@` sign.  After this, `git am` should accept it.

---

If you have access to the git repository you can use the regular commands,

1. `git checkout oldbranch`
2. `git format-patch HEAD~4` This will make four files that are patches of the last changes (change the number for your case).
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git am *.patch`

You get the same commit ids, messages, etc as the remote repository which can be useful later.

---

Tools like *gitk* and *kdiff* do **NOT** generate the same data as *format-patch* and you don't get the commit history.  If you have this type of data, you must use `git apply` or generate patches as above.

See: [Difference between git format-patch and git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624127/what-is-the-difference-between-git-format-patch-and-git-diff).

Comment: After adding email address in the .patch file, git whines about lacking SHA hash. I guess I will try GoZoner's answer.

Comment: I have my local repo, into which some source code was copied a year ago from foreign project. Meanwhile that project was updated, as well as my local repo. I want to incorporate foreign improvements. I made a patch of changes made to foreign project by copying latest version into old branch and showing all the differences. I still haven't found a tool which will apply this unified diff to my local repo.

Comment: I finally did it with kdiff3, but not using the patch which I have previously created.

Answer (score 1):

If it's more helpful for you to use a graphical interface instead of the command line, there are quite a few tools out there that make it relatively simple to do lots of things in Git, including apply patches). The most helpful one that I've found is [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com), but I'm sure there's other nice ones out there if you search.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have this error if your commit message has a line that begins with `From:`.  For instance, I had a patch where I fixed a typo, and in the body of the commit message I had:

```
Fixes a typo.
From: 873524cab1 "Introduced some bug on this commit"
```

The .patch file, generated by format-patch had two `From:` lines, one of which was the email address, and the other was my lousy message.  Git am was picking up the second `From:` line and trying to find the email address.

The fix was to change the commit message to not have `From:` at the beginning of a line.