# Patch does not have a valid e-mail address after `git am`

Tags: git, git-branch

After:

```
git am --signoff < /tmp/diff_api_public.patch
```

Output was:

```
Patch does not have a valid e-mail address.
```

And now, I have the repository in the state:

```
project-folder[branch-name|AM 1/1]$
```

What's next to regain the branch correct?

Comment: Nothing: you should have a new commit on that branch now (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2250170/6309)

Comment: thanks @VonC . But what's **AM 1/1** mean? . And How to make it go away?

Comment: What `git status` returns?

Comment: @VonC
On branch 
You are in the middle of an am session.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git am --continue")
  (use "git am --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git am --abort" to restore the original branch)

Comment: Sorry @VonC I forgot to say that the output of the git am was `Patch does not have a valid e-mail address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f4ba4b6e3ba7075ca6b379ba23fd3088cbe69a8/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L407-L408), this particular prompt is displayed where there is a `.git/rebase-apply/applying` file.

That should means the path was applied with conflict.
Or, in this instance, that the patch wasn't applied fully (`Patch does not have a valid e-mail address`)

The status is clear:

- use "`git am --skip`" to skip this patch
- use "`git am --abort`" to restore the original branch

As a workaround, in order to apply that patch, you an have a look at "[git: Patch does not have a valid e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349248/6309)".

- either use `git apply`
- or edit the patch to add the proper email.

Comment: The problem was the `Patch does not have a valid e-mail address`. I don't have conflict markers. If I `git am --continue` the output is `Patch does not have a valid e-mail address`