# git: generate a single patch across multiple commits

Tags: git, patch

This is the situation:

1. We created a "private" repo (say our-repo) based off an existing open-source git repo (say source-repo).
2. We have been developing code and have around 20 merges into our repo. So, the repo moved from "State_Initial" to "State_Current".

Now, for business reasons, we want to hand-over all our development to a third party. Based on some legal issues, the only option is we give them a "single" patch file with all our changes. That is a squashed patch between "State_Initial" and "State_Current".

I looked around, and found

```
git format-patch -X
```

But, it generates "n" .patch files.

Is there a way to create a single patch file, so that if we create a repo based off "source-repo" and apply the patch, it takes us to "State_Current"?

Answer (score 110):

The following command creates a single `.patch` file that contains multiple commits.

```
git format-patch cc1dde0dd^..6de6d4b06 --stdout > foo.patch
```

You can then apply it like so:

```
git am foo.patch
```

**Note:** Be sure to use `^..` instead of `..` if you want the first commit SHA to be included.

Comment: **Warning:** This produces one file containing multiple separate patches. It doesn't squash the history down as requested in the question. If there are sensitive commits in the middle they'll be exposed.

Comment: If you want to squash multiple commits into a patch then you can squash them by rebasing and then can make the squashed commit as a patch.

Comment: Just to clarify (maybe for Windows users only?). This command resulted in an error for me when doing the "git am foo.patch" part. I got a "Patch: format detection failed" error. What worked was to create the patch using the command:
git format-patch cc1dde0dd^..6de6d4b06 --output=foo.patch

Comment: @ThermoX Were you using PowerShell?

From my testing it seems that If you run the --stdout version of the command from PowerShell you'll get a UTF-16 LE BOM-encoded file with Windows line endings instead of a UTF-8–encoded file with UNIX line endings, and that's probably why the patch doesn't apply cleanly.

So use Git Bash or cmd.exe for best results.

Comment: @Jordan Bradford Yes, I was using PowerShell with the posh-git extension. I probably should have mentioned that in my original comment. Looking at the encoding, I *am* getting UTF-8 for the --output version, while as I am getting UCS-2 LE BOM for the --stdout. When running this under a cmd shell, you are correct. They both come out at UTF-8. However, I then need to use ^^ instead of ^. So I just keep using PowerShell and the --output version, which works fine. But glad to know the reason --stdout wasn't working there.

Comment: For the curious, this is the official git [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_commit_ranges) for selecting ranges of commits based on `..` and `^` syntax

Comment: As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624204/7446465), `git format-patch` may be preferred over `git diff` since it includes metadata for the changes (i.e. committer identity, timestamps, commit messages, etc)

Comment: @AddisonKlinke: Note that precisely this can be what is desired, when the goal is to see how the code is different.

Answer (score 25):

You can generate a single-file patch between <COMMIT1> and <COMMIT2> like this:

#### With commit history

Generate patch:

```
git format-patch <COMMIT1>^..<COMMIT2> --stdout > commits.patch
```

Apply patch:

```
git am commits.patch
```

#### Without commit history

Generate patch:

```
git diff <COMMIT1>^..<COMMIT2> > diff.patch
```

Apply patch:

```
git apply diff.patch
```

#### Notes

- On Windows, you'd better run the above command in Git Bash. If you use PowerShell and get error when apply the patch, you can try to convert the patch file to UTF-8 encoding.
- If you for some reason want to include the first commit into the patch. You can do:

  ```
  git format-patch --root --stdout > all.patch
  ```

  or

  ```
  git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD > diff.patch
  ```

  The 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 represents the "empty tree", see [How to get Git diff of the first commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883798/how-to-get-git-diff-of-the-first-commit)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new branch named `squashed` that has a single [squashed commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486788/68587). This branch will have the exact same contents as your normal branch but none of the history.

Look it over and if you're satisfied, use `format-patch` to create a patch file.

```
$ git checkout -b squashed $(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -m 'Squashed history')
$ git format-patch --root HEAD
```

This is a non-destructive operation and you can switch right back to your normal development branch afterwards. You can `tag` the squashed branch to save a reference to what you e-mailed them, or use `branch -D` to delete it if you no longer need it.

```
$ git branch -D squashed
```

Comment: How do you specify the start of the commit range, though? It looks like this captures _all_ of the files of the branch in a single commit, going back to the initial commit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git diff`:

`git diff 0f3063094850 > ./test.patch`

Comment: Useful, but a bit laconic. I think this means, "_To get a patch of the diff between your current status and a specific commit, execute `git diff [otherCommitSHA] > test.patch`_"-- as that's what this seems to do. That command doesn't appear to create the same patch format as the patch command, but you can learn about exactly [what patch formats can be used here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_generating_patch_text_with_p).

Answer (score 3):

"The last 10 patches from head in a single patch files:"

`git format-patch -10 HEAD --stdout > 0001-last-10-commits.patch`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172120/9478470 an answer to similar question: [How can I generate a Git patch for a specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/how-can-i-generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit#comment51607318_6658352)

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you do not wish to create a throwaway branch and squash all your commits between `state_initial` and `state_current` and then use `git format-patch`, there is an alternative. If you branched out from state_initial and your branch is rebased on top of the source branch:

`git format-patch source_branch <patch_file_name>`

When you do `git am <patch_file_name>`, it will not reconstruct your entire commit chain. But this patch file will be a sequential list of changes. If you have changed and changed back things across multiple commits, it can still be visible if someone examines the patch file.

Answer (score -1):

use this command:

```
$ git format-patch -n <commit string>
```

-n means how many commits you want to generate for this patch, and  means which commit you want to generate from.

Comment: This will generate one patch per commit

Answer (score -2):

`git format-patch` can take a revision range as an argument. See `git help format-patch`:

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> git format-patch [-k] [(-o|--output-directory) <dir> | --stdout]
>                    ... (many flags omitted)
>                    [--progress]
>                    [<common diff options>]
>                    [ <since> | <revision range> ]
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> …
>
> There are two ways to specify which commits to operate on.
>
> 1. A single commit, `<since>`, specifies that the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the `<since>` to be output.
> 2. Generic `<revision range>` expression (see "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" section in **gitrevisions**(7)) means the commits in the specified range.

For example, the following command generates a patch for the last three commits on the current branch:

```
git format-patch HEAD~3..HEAD
```

Comment: That generates one `.patch` file per commit. The asker wants a single `.patch` file that contains all commits in the given range.